# iOS - Build fails with CocoaPods cannot find header files

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, build, cocoapods

I have an iOS project using CocoaPods. Everything was working smoothly until another developer started to work on the same project. He made some changes (only to code as far as I know) and made a new branch in the repo. I have checked out his branch and tried to build it, but I am getting an error: ASLogger/ASLogger.h file not found.

Even if I delete the whole project and make a fresh copy and use 'pods install .' the build failure is still there. Do you have any idea where the problem can be? If you need some more infos, just ask.

Comment: Instead of using double quote style, #import "ASLogger.h" i tried this, #import <ASLogger.h> And it worked for me :)

Comment: FYI: Baigs simple answer solved my issue with not finding the header.

Answer (score 209):

*Update*

Make sure your `Podfile` includes `link_with` on targets missing a config file. Cocoapods only [sets the first target by default](http://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html) otherwise. e.g.

```
platform :osx, '10.7'
pod 'JSONKit',       '~> 1.4'

link_with 'Pomo', 'Pomo Dev', 'Pomo Tests'
```

*------ End Update*

---

**Note: Please do note that you have to look into Project->Info->Configurations for steps below.**

---

I had similar symptoms and found that the `pods.xcconfig` file was not being included in the specific `target` I was trying to build.  Some of the other suggested solutions worked for me, but this one seemed to address part of the underlying issue.

[image: Pods.xcconfig not working]

The simple solution was to change set the configuration file for the targets that didn't have one set.

[image: Pods.xcconfig working]

Comment: For me, ''pods install'' only set this on the first target.  Doing as suggested in this answer solved my problem.

Comment: Finally a solution: Pods was added ONLY to first target, not to various test release targets (alpha, beta, release candidate)! Great many thanx!

Comment: Using `link_with` to specify my other target worked for me. Many thanks. I just spent several hours on this.

Comment: this worked for me!  i cloned an existing project, and then updated pods. so i am guessing updating pods flipped some settings, or the previos dev was using xcode 5 or something (i'm on xcode 6), thanks!!!

Comment: Great work! On Xcode 6 I can't find Project->Info, but by changing the Podfile and then doing 'pod update' I finally got my project working.

Comment: Set configuration for Test target worked for me. Even if I'm not building (or even using) Test target at all!

Comment: This worked for me with a slight modification to also set Pods.* on the actual "project" (top-level Pomo in this case).

Comment: @Troy: where I find that Configurations in latest version of `XCode Version 7.0 (7A220)` ?

Comment: @joacar Same place as pictured, but be sure to click "Info" at the top of the window (vs. "Build Settings")

Comment: link_with is no longer supported, so what's the best way to do this now (without having to muck about in XCode settings)?

Comment: Yes, make sure you're looking at the project settings, not the target settings, but otherwise it still seems to be there, and this solved my header search failure.

Comment: If you came across this problem after migrating to `use_frameworks!` see my answer below.

Comment: `link_with` is unsupported in Cocoapods 1.0 or higher.

Comment: I seeing the same issue, none of pod thing is applied to second target. I think its cocoapods version 1 problem too. But I am not able to find this configuration screens in xcode 7.3. Any one can help please. wasted whole 2 days and million branches. plus non of the pod are visible too :(

Comment: I had been switching between two targets and even though I was building for a target that had the correct configurations. The target that had no configurations (that I wasn't even building) was somehow effecting it. So; make sure your configurations are correct for all targets!!!!!

Comment: @Vive is correct that "link_with" is unsupported. We should use "target" instead. So in this sample it should be changed like that >>> target 'Pomo', 'Pomo Dev', 'Pomo Tests'

Answer (score 98):

If the headers aren't being imported, you probably have a conflict in the `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS`. Try and add `$(inherited)` to the header search paths in your Build Settings to make sure that it pulls in any search paths included in the .xcconfig file from your CocoaPods.

This should help with any conflicts and get your source imported correctly.

Comment: I had faced issue:Pod files were not getting detected in app and 'svn obstructed folder issue' which occurs when you have deleted or moved the .svn subdirectories:
Solution: by following steps:
1.Uninstall CocoaPods from app so only . xcodeproj file exists (referred : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427421/how-to-remove-cocoapods-from-a-project)
2.Installed podfiles again (referred: http://www.raywenderlich.com/12139/introduction-to-cocoapods)
3. $(inherited) flag added in target 'HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS' and 'OTHER_LDFLAGS' of the app.

Comment: You may also need to add $(inherited) to your FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS setting.

Comment: @AlphonseR.Dsouza your solution worked for me - added $(inherited) to OTHER_LDFLAGS thanks a million!

Comment: $(inherited) should be added in project settings or target settings?

Comment: I had similar problem, I had no past experience with pods. In the Podfile also, I didnt mention 2 targets. Yes I was having 2 targets. Once I mentioned the 2nd target and updated the Pod file, teh terminal stated some warning similar to your suggestion to add $inherrited. I did and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @Bill Burgess where do I need to add that inherited word? in the Build Settings of my main project or in the PODs project?

Comment: Just search your build settings for the listed key, then add it there.

Comment: TFW you solve your own problem... again after 9 years. Thanks me!

Answer (score 85):

1.Check

> build settings -> Search Path -> User Header Search Paths ->

- **"${PODS_ROOT}/"  recursive**

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

2.Check import style(KEY POINT), 
if your's `podfile` have set

**`use_frameworks!`**

In yours `File-Bridging-Header.h`,the formatter should like this

**`#import "MBProgressHUD.h"`**

else should be below

**`#import <MBProgressHUD.h>`**

3.That must be work! trust me

Comment: Most errors disappear. However what shall I do when a dependency has an import statement like: #import <EARestrictedScrollView/EARestrictedScrollView.h>.

Then the compiler tells me to instead write #import EARestrictedScrollView.h. But I can't modify my pod.

Answer (score 64):

Header files, you'll be the death of me...

Finally got it to work by adding (including quotes)

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/BuildHeaders"
```

to the User Header Search Paths entry, and checking 'recursive'.

Comment: Note that the quotes are very important here.  Without them, I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: +1 I already had `$(inherited)` (wasn't working) but adding this worked for me.

Comment: Did not get what you are trying to say. :/ Caould you please elaborate?

Comment: Another handy trick is to blow away the workspace and pods directory and pod install fresh. This is generally a more complete solution.

Comment: This finally helped AppCode to correctly find all header file imports. Without this, it worked in xCode, but not in AppCode. Thanks!

Comment: @averydev Hi i have same problem but dont know where do I have to add ${PODS_ROOT}/BuildHeaders. Do you have any screenshot please. Appreciate it

Comment: @averydev there appears to columns with my project name can you help that did not work for me ?

Answer (score 54):

I found `${PODS_HEADERS_SEARCH_PATHS}` is missing and it is not defined in my develop git branch, So I added  `"$(SRCROOT)/Pods/Headers/"` for Header Search Paths with recursive

That is ok for me

Comment: This was the answer for me, I updated cocoapods and I think that made the PODS_HEADERS_SEARCH_PATHS go away.  My solution was similar to this but I used "$(PODS_ROOT)/Headers"

Comment: The other answers did not work for me, but this one did. I'll note that I didn't include the ", so my header search path looks like this ```$(SRCROOT)/Pods/Headers```

Comment: @Hlung hi, where do I have to add $(SRCROOT)/Pods/Headers/ ? Appreciate it

Comment: @VAAA Target > Build Settings > Header search path

Comment: i think this is the right answer what should be accepted, what do you think @Filip Majernik

Answer (score 36):

Both other answers didn't help here. I found 2 other problems that might fix it:

- The Project->Info->Configurations in the Xcode project (your project) should be set to 'Pods' for Debug, Release (and whatelse you have). See ["Headers not found – search paths not included"](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/670)
- Maybe you have to link the target with the link_with command. See ["Unable to find headers in Static Library project"](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/701)

**EDIT** 
You can check a symlink this way: create a textfile named 'check' without an extension. copy these lines into it:

```
file=/Users/youUserName/XcodeProjectName/Pods/BuildHeaders/SVProgressHUD/SVProgressHUD.h
if [[ ! -e $file &&  -L $file ]]; then
  echo "$file symlink is  broken!"
else
  echo "symlink works"
fi
```

Then go to the terminal, change to the folder where your check file is located and type

```
bash check
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The first entry solved it for me. Pods was set for the first target in our project only. This compiled fine, but the other target didn't. So I added the Pods configuration to it as well and now the issue is gone.

Comment: I dont see 'Pods' in the Configurations .. does this mean my symlink is broken?

Answer (score 34):

Here's what worked for me:

Go to the Target > "Build Settings" tab and find the "User Header Search Paths" setting.

Set this to "$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)" and check the "Recursive" check box.

Now the built target will search the workspace’s shared build directory to locate the linkable header files.

====

UPDATE

I had a similar (although slightly different) problem recently. It turned out Xcode couldn't find the Pods because I had opened up the `.xcodeproj` file rather than the `.xcworkspace` file. Might help others in the future.

Comment: This worked for me, but only after quitting Xcode, running `pod install`, and re-opening.

Comment: @Snowcrash what Target? the pod target or the main project target?

Answer (score 19):

If none of the above worked for you and you are finding this error because you just switched to `use_frameworks!` in your Podfile, read on:

I tried all the solutions above and a lot more before learning that it isn't about search header paths at all in my particular case; it's that when you switch to `use_frameworks!` in your Podfile you no longer need to include frameworks in your bridging header, and in fact Xcode will throw the very unhelpful "unable to find header" error.

What you need to do is remove all imports from your bridging header file, and instead use the Swift `import Module` in your individual Swift files as needed, just like you would for Swift frameworks.

AND if you are using any of the framework headers in your Obj-C classes (in my case we have a convenience class that used the FBSDK) you need to change it from a local to global import (this means change `#import "Module.h"` to `#import <Module/Module.h>`, which should autocomplete for you when you begin to type the framework name. In my case it was `<AFNetworking/AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.h>`).

Edit: I've since learned that doing an `@import Module` uses the umbrella file which is even safer.

Answer (score 18):

Did you try importing Cocoapods style?

```
#import <ASLogger.h>
```

The info on the site is not really clear, I submitted a pull request:

https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods.org/pull/34

**Update:** They pulled my request :)

Comment: Instead of using double quote style,
    
    #import "ASLogger.h"

i tried this,

    #import <ASLogger.h>

And it worked for me :)

Comment: I've tried this before and it has worked for me, but sometimes a different problems occurs when it doesn't work. You can also use <Podname/Filename.h> format in at least some situations.

Comment: Yes this worked for me too! No amount of cleaning and deleting the derived data resolved it, but this worked.

Answer (score 11):

The [wiki](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/wiki/Creating-a-project-that-uses-CocoaPods/2c6eb4b8b3a169d350891ce7005f9715f6a6ec4d) gives an advice on how to solve this problem:

> If Xcode can’t find the headers of the dependencies:
>
> Check if the pod header files are correctly symlinked in Pods/Headers
>   and you are not overriding the HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS (see #1). If Xcode
>   still can’t find them, as a last resort you can prepend your imports,
>   e.g. #import "Pods/SSZipArchive.h".

Comment: Could someone elaborate on exactly how to "Check if the pod header files are correctly symlinked in Pods/Headers" please?

Comment: please see my answer above for how to check a symlink

Comment: Please also see brainray's answer about Configurations before you mangle your import statements.

Comment: yes, some pods are linking to an invalid directory, like `$(PROJECT_DIR)/Pods/Headers/Public/xxx/ios/xxx.h`, there is an extra of `ios` folder...

Answer (score 9):

I was the only developer in the team experiencing this same issue, it worked perfectly for everybody so I realized it had to be my environment. I tried a `git clone` of the same project in another directory and it compiled perfectly, then I realized it had to be Xcode caching stuff for my project path somewhere, that "somewhere" is the DerivedData folder, just remove it and do a clean build of your project, it worked for me.

You can get the path and even open the folder in finder by going to:

**Xcode** -> **Preferences** -> **Locations -> **DerivedData**

Comment: In my case problem appeared after updating pods, so I thought in  cocoapods should search the problem. I've tried all solutions here with no luck and finally just cleared DerivedData - and it helped! thank you

Answer (score 4):

I will update the below things in my Build settings and I did not get any errors. To check these are the things while updating your cocoapods.

**Build Settings**

> Enable Bit code - YES(if you are using bitcode)
>
> Macro preprocessor - $(inherited)
>
> Other linker flag - objc, -lc++, $(inherited)

**Build architecture only**

> Debug - Yes
>
> Relese - No

**Search Path**

> Framework search path - $(inherited) $(PROJECT_DIR)
>
> Library search path - $(inherited)
>
> Header search path - $(inherited)

Answer (score 4):

For me, what fixed it was the iOS deployment target for my Pods project was lower than my project itself. Once I made it the same as my project it was able to find the header file.

Comment: bro ! you deserve 1000 upvotes . i was stuck with this for 4 hours and your solution helped me out . thanks alot bro thanks alot !

Answer (score 2):

If you had the building errors after a "**pod install**" or a "**pod update**", it may be that one of your pods have been built with **XCode 6.3** while you are still using a previous version.

In my case I had to update my OSX from mavericks to Yosemite to have Xcode 6.3 and solve the problem

Comment: Hi @omaty, is this the only solution? I'm currently running on Mavericks with Xcode 6.2

Comment: Hello @goelv in my case it was the only solution I found. I was like you under Mavericks and Xcode 6.2.

Comment: I think even I have same issue. My teammate has Xcode 6.3 in Yosemite and it works fine for him, whereas I am struggling to get rid of the header not found issue in Mavericks in Xcode 6.2.

Comment: Follow up: I also upgraded the machine to Yosemite and Xcode 6.3.1, I am able to build without any issues now.

Answer (score 1):

for me the problem was in Other Linker flags value. For some reason I had no quotes in flags like `-l"xml2"` `-l"Pods-MBProgressHUD"`.

Comment: I was having problems with Localytics' Cocoapod. Under `Other Linker Flags` I found two entries: `-|Localytics` and `|-PodsLocalytics`. I removed those and then was able to compile.

Answer (score 1):

I had to download the zip from git hub and drag the missing files into the Finder at corresponding paths in Pod/...

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was selecting the Pods project, finding and selecting the target framework with the missing header in the Pod project's target directory and setting "Build Active Architecture Only" to "No" under "Architectures" in the target's build settings.

Answer (score 1):

I have got the same problem, but the above solutions can't work.
I have fixed it by doing this:

1. Remove the whole project
2. Run git clone the project and run the bundle exec pod install
3. cd the peoject and run remote add upstream your-remote-rep-add
4. git fetch upstream
5. git checkout master
6. git merge upstream/master

And then it works.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into similar issue while running an Objective-C code on my M1 Macbook Pro. It was running completely fine on Intel based Macs.

This is how I solved my issue:

Copy your pods from Podfile and then run following commands using Terminal.

```
sudo gem install cocoapods-deintegrate cocoapods-clean

pod deintegrate

pod cache clean --all

rm Podfile

rm Podfile.lock

pod init
```

Paste your copied pods into the Podfile and run following command on Terminal.

```
pod install
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was on the GM seed of Xcode 5.0 and I couldn't get any of these answers to work.  I tried every single answer on SO on multiple different questions about header imports w/ cocoapods.

**FINALLY I found a solution that worked for me**: I upgraded to Xcode 5.0 via the Mac AppStore (installed on top of the GM seed) and now the header imports are working as expected.

I also still had a beta version of Xcode 5 on my system and I deleted that as well.  Maybe it was a combination of the two things, but hopefully this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

This was the answer for me, I updated cocoapods and I think that made the PODS_HEADERS_SEARCH_PATHS go away. My solution was similar to this but I used "$(PODS_ROOT)/Headers" –  Andrew Aitken

Thank you so much for this answer. I had a hard time looking for ways to fix my problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers helped me (I had my pods linked with all targets, build configurations setup properly, correclty set search paths "$(inherited)", etc...).

Problem disappeared by itself after I updated cocoapods to the newest, debug version using standard install / update command:

```
   gem install cocoapods --pre
```

or:

```
   sudo gem install cocoapods --pre
```

(if sudo was used during installation).

It must have been cocoapods bug.

Answer (score 0):

One simple workaround is: 
1. Delete Pods folder and Podfile.lock file. But don't delete Podfile
2. Run following command in your project root folder:

```
pod install
```

Comment: I fixed my problem with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another reason: All the header paths seemed fine, but we still had an error in the precompiled (.pch) file trying to read a pod header

(i.e. #import <CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack.h>).

Looking at the raw build output, I finally noticed that the error was breaking our Watch OS Extension Target, not the main target we were building, because we were also importing the .pch precompiled header file into the Watch OS targets, and it was failing there.  Make sure your accompanying Watch OS target settings don't try to import the .pch file (especially if you set that import from the master target setting, like I did!)

Answer (score 0):

I've found that including the library as a pod install directly helps dynamic libraries. For example, for Firebase:

```
pod 'RNFirebase', :path => 'path/to/node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios'
```

Or for ASLogger:

```
pod 'ASLogger', :path => 'path/to/node_modules/aslogger/ios' // path to header files
```

Changing or hardcoding `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` did not help me. If the error ever recurs, it's not necessary to `rm -rf node_modules` nor delete the pod file etc, I found it useful to clear the cache.

For react-native, I run

```
    rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-native-packager-cache-*
    rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-bundler-cache-*
    rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-* 
    rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-* 
    rm -rf $TMPDIR/haste-*
    rm -rf "$(getconf DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR)/org.llvm.clang/ModuleCache"
    npm start -- --reset-cache
```

For Xcode I remove folders in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`

Answer (score 0):

I think an ultimate solution is to go to `Build settings -> Search Path -> User Header Search Paths`, find your library path and go through it in a Finder. Make sure that all path exists including your import path.

For me my path was shorter than in a tutorial. In tutorial it was something like `#import <SDK/path/to/sdk/File.h>`, but turns out it is just `#import <SDK/File.h>`

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Xcode 12 or above, **make sure your Pods are being compiled for the correct architecture (Intel vs. ARM)**.  Check to see if you have a `VALID_ARCHS` or `EXCLUDED_ARCHS` setting anywhere.

I had `config.build_settings['EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]'] = 'arm64'` in my Podfile, and that prevented the compiler from finding the Pod header files.

Answer (score -2):

Have a try to comment this line for your target

```
#  use_frameworks!
```

Or you can refer to my another answer  [added unit testing target to xcode - failed to import bridging header won't go away](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28343493/added-unit-testing-target-to-xcode-failed-to-import-bridging-header-wont-go-a/38630679#38630679)

Answer (score -2):

I solved this issues for Xcode 8.2.1 by drag and drop framework that i want to use.

Answer (score -2):

I have other worked solution here,

1. Quit Xcode
2. Open Xcode and clean project
3. Build Pods project first
4. Build Project