# Output Build options in Xcode

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I'm trying to debug why CocoaPods isn't working.

There's a similar post here which hasn't worked for me: [iOS - Build fails with CocoaPods cannot find header files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002905/ios-build-fails-with-cocoapods-cannot-find-header-files)

The definitive CocoaPods article seems to be this: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/wiki/Creating-a-project-that-uses-CocoaPods

which suggests: "If something doesn’t seem to work, first of all ensure that you are not completely overriding any options set from the Pods.xcconfig file in your project’s build settings. To add values to options from your project’s build settings, prepend the value list with $(inherited)."

I'm not clear what they mean by "prepend the value list with $(inherited)". I assume they mean to prepend the Header Search Paths with this which I've tried and hasn't worked. However, I've set up a brand new project and added CocoaPods so I assume I'm not overriding any options set in the Pods.xcconfig file. I would like to test the values of these options though - e.g.

```
PODS_ROOT = ${SRCROOT}/Pods
```

might be a good starting point.

How do I go about outputting this in the console during the Build phase?
Or is there a different way of examining these as the files do not come up when I try and autocomplete them?

E.g.

```
#import "AFNetworking.h"
```

won't autocomplete even though it has been installed and set up by CocoaPods

Comment: I've found that it won't always autocomplete right away, but the project usually builds just fine. Otherwise you just need to add '$(inherited)' to the other linker flags and/or public headers search path. This will include any existing flags/paths you might have as well as include any from the xcconfig file.

Comment: I realize this is probably a stale question given that cocoa pods 0.22.1 seems to instead use PODS_ROOT then build up HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS based on that. However, did you ever get an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

As Bill Burgess has said, you need to make sure that your header search paths includes $(inherited). I also added */Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include* to the search path. My project both builds and gives me auto complete for the standard classes and those in the Pod project.

Hope this helps.