# How to make changes to a component added via Cocoapods

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoapods

I'm using a component called [AMPopTip](https://github.com/andreamazz/AMPopTip), which is working well, but I want to make one change to it (to add some padding so that the pop-up doesn't touch the edge of the screen). I can see where in the code to make the change - in the setup function - but of course I don't want the changes to be overwritten when I update my pods.

I could create a subclass, but the change is right in the middle of a huge function so overriding that entire function doesn't seem like a great idea. Is there a better way?

Many thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing an imported library using cocoapods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17469413/changing-an-imported-library-using-cocoapods)

Answer (score 1):

There is a way exist where you can fork the repository , modify the changes and maintain the library through cocoapods for future bug fixes and feature enhancement ..... 
[image]

I have written article on the same explain the entire process. You can find it [here](https://medium.com/@mihirpmehta/how-to-modify-cocoapods-library-within-pods-647d2bf7e1cb)