# Cocoapods can't find header after checkout from github

Tags: ios, github, cocoapods

I updated the cocoapods then push it on github that is working fine on my machine, when I took the pull on another machine then it shows the header error."can't find header"

Comment: Please provide more details. What do you mean "updated the cocoapods then push it on github"? Did you update podspec? Did you update project that uses cocoapods?

Comment: I have pod file in which AFNetworking and many more SDK are added then I added google analytics and then I run the pod update command.

Comment: Did you run `pod install` on fresh project to make cocoapods downloaded and injected into your project?

Comment: We are working on project whose repo is on GitHub. In that project pod file is already present because I am not working on that from scratch. Now I have to add google analytics in that project so I changed the pod file and run the pod update command, its working fine. Then I push my code to repo when other developer taking pull he is facing header file missing error(all files are there). As you suggested I took the new clone(I am also facing same error) and run the pod install command then its working fine on my end and push to repo but other dev still facing same issue after pull from repo.

Comment: Did you try solutions from these topics: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14512792/libraries-not-found-when-using-cocoapods-with-ios-logic-tests, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17755898/cocoapods-generates-invalid-project-file-header-not-found ?

Comment: Thanks Max for your response. I am still facing same problem. Yes I have tried all the options given in the above link. I think this issue is related to version control. May be some issue occurring while committing google analytics library.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72118/discussion-between-abhinav-and-max-k).

Comment: Please add contents of your `Podfile`, and the code that causing error.

Comment: platform :ios, '7.0'
workspace 'test'
xcodeproj 'test'

pod 'AFNetworking',     '~> 2.2', :inhibit_warnings => true
pod 'AFDownloadRequestOperation', '~> 2.0.1', :inhibit_warnings => true
pod 'GoogleAnalytics-iOS-SDK','~> 3.10'

pod 'SSZipArchive',     :inhibit_warnings => true

post_install do | installer |
  require 'fileutils'
  FileUtils.cp_r('Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods-Acknowledgements.plist', 'test/Supporting Files/Settings.bundle/Acknowledgements.plist', :remove_destination => true)
  `/bin/bash update_acknowledgements.sh`
end

Comment: or can we do the chat my skype Id :- abhi.rkgit, gmail id :- abhi.rkgit@gmail.com