# Cocoapods link_with XCTest generates duplicate symbol errors

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

I have this main project that will generate a static library (call it `MySDK`).  I have a component (call it `Analytics`) as a private cocoapod.

So I end up with a file structure like this:

```
+ MySDK
    - src
+ Pods
    + Pods
        - Analytics
```

Each project has it's own tests, but now I need to do some integration testing so in my Podfile I use `link_with`, but whenever I do this I can't even run the original tests because I get a bunch of `duplicate symbol` errors:

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PodsDummy_Pods in:
    /.../DerivedData/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(Pods-dummy.o)
    /.../DerivedData/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/libMySDK.a(Pods-dummy.o)
...
duplicate symbol _MYPREFIXFileTableIDColumnName in:
    /.../DerivedData/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(MYPREFIXDatabaseConstants.o)
    /.../Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/libMySDK.a(MYPREFIXDatabaseConstants.o)
```

All the errors come from my `Analytics` component.  All the files causing a problem have **C functions** (I'm dealing with sqlite directly) and/or (global) **constants**, or they are **categories**, but they're all prefixed.

My `Podfile` looks like this:

```
platform :ios, '7.0'
link_with ['MySDK', 'MySDKTests']
pod 'Analytics', '0.0.1'
```

My podscpec for `Analytics` looks like this:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name     = 'Analytics'
  s.version  = '0.0.1'
  s.platform = :ios
  s.summary  = "Analytics utility"
  s.homepage = 'http://google.com'
  s.author   = { 'Me' => 'me@me.com' }
  s.source   = { :git => 'https://github.com/Company/Analytics.git', :tag => '0.0.1' }
  s.source_files = 'Analytics/**/*.{h,m}'
  s.requires_arc = true
  s.ios.deployment_target = '6.0'
end
```

Is there a reason why I'm getting these errors? Should I compile these files as non-arc or use some special flag?

Any ideas

Comment: Looks like you have something included or imported multiple times.

Comment: I know, but I can't figure out what it is.  Those files are brought in by cocoapods and they shouldn't be included/imported more than once, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got it to work!

I shouldn't have linked my pods to `MySDKTests`, since the final product (`MySDK`, a library, was already linking against `Analytics`).

I did however add the following to my `podspec` file:

```
  s.public_header_files = 'Analytics/**/*.h'

  s.xcconfig = { 'HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS' => '"$(SRCROOT)/Pods/Headers/Analytics"' }
```

The second line is not really necessary because it's not modifying my `MySDKTests` target. I did have to add `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` to my `MyDSKTests` to make those headers available to the tests.

I've read that some people successfully use `LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS` instead, but this didn't work for me.  If anyone care to explain why, that'd be great, but for now I'll leave my solution here for other people in case they come across similar issue.

See [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002905/ios-build-fails-with-cocoapods-cannot-find-header-files) for related info

Comment: "pod 'Analytics', '0.0.1'" Is this your private pod? Can you share exact steps to have private pods and how to integrate it?

Comment: @harshit2811 I can't remember the exact steps, but here's some info http://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html and a good Google search will give you good instructions (https://www.google.com/search?q=private%20cocoapod%20tutorial)