# Compiler errors on Xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6

I updated to Xcode 6 a while ago, I had absolutely no errors on Xcode 5.1.1
Getting some weird and totally illogical errors when compiling in Xcode 6. I went through all of them but I seriously have no idea why these errors are appearing only on Xcode 6.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/z255siefabr8xtv/Screenshot%202014-10-04%2009.56.35.png
https://www.dropbox.com/s/19hcoi4068semuo/Screenshot%202014-10-04%2009.56.50.png

All these errors are on the dependency Pods and their methods which I've used in my native code. None of these errors are occurring in my code except the external library methods which are being called inside my code

Comment: Did you try a `pod install` again? I am guessing that the header files are not being imported properly. See this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002905/ios-build-fails-with-cocoapods-cannot-find-header-files/16703468#16703468

Comment: Yes tried the `pod install` many times already. Nothing works

Comment: Not sure, where exactly is wrong. Did you check the above link? Could be the header path. On SO, there are multiple threads addressing the same issue, but none of them have an upvoted answer.

Comment: None of the solutions worked for me. The one you suggested, I have only single target for my app so that doesn't work either

Comment: If you can create a simplified version of your project, do you still get those errors on Xcode 6? I'll be happy to look at them if you can share the simplified version.

Comment: By simplified, you mean removing all the Pods?

Comment: Not writing any of your code. Just installing Pods.

Comment: This is my [Podfile](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/42834001/Teamie/Podfile)

iOS Deployment Target is 6.0

Comment: I created a new project and added this [Podfile](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/42834001/Teamie/Podfile) and built using Xcode 6. Still the same errors

Answer (score 0):

Yes, those errors are all related to compatibility. On Terminal, inside your project directory - I did a `rm -rf ~/.cocoapods` followed by, `sudo gem install cocoapods` on the terminal.

And now, before we do `pod install`. You modify your *PodFile*. Instead of a version, you can specify the `:head` flag. This will use the pod’s latest version spec version, but force the download of the ‘bleeding edge’ version [[Source]](http://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html). A spec might not be compatible with the source material anymore.

`ECSlidingViewController` was one example. This is how your *PodFile* should look like -

```
source 'https://github.com/artsy/Specs.git'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '6.0'
inhibit_all_warnings!

# Frameworks
pod 'RestKit', :head

# UI
pod 'FlatUIKit', :head
pod 'SVProgressHUD', :head
pod 'SDWebImage', :head
pod 'MKNumberBadgeView', :head
pod 'TDBadgedCell', :head
pod 'EMAccordionTableViewController', :head

# Controls
pod 'TSMessages', :head
pod 'ECSlidingViewController', '0.10.0'
pod 'SVPullToRefresh', :head
pod 'WEPopover', :head
pod 'SVWebViewController', :head
pod 'EGOPhotoViewer', :head
pod 'DACircularProgress', :head

# Tools
pod 'FontAwesomeIconFactory', :head
pod 'KeychainItemWrapper', :head
pod 'DAKeyboardControl', :head
pod 'ARAnalytics/GoogleAnalytics', :head
pod 'Instabug', :head

# Categories
pod 'NSData+Base64', :head
```

Comment: You might get one error with WEPopover. The fix is very simple, I raised an issue here - https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover/issues/57

Comment: I tried this method. I don't get any errors with it. But I'm using a specific versions of specs purposely. I am not willing to update to the newer specs right now as some of them would require architecture change and would have to change a lot of code in my app. The errors still exist :(

Comment: I doubt its a good idea to continue maintaining older versions. You can start a bounty on the question if it remains unanswered. I tried my best :)