# Cocoapods - 'MBProgressHUD.h not found' after installing pod and verifying file exists

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods, mbprogresshud

I've added the *MBProgressHUD* Cocoapod to my project. Here is my *Podfile*:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '8.0'

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

target 'RRiOSApp' do

pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.8'

end

target 'RRiOSAppTests' do

end
```

I now have my code open as an Xcode workspace instead of a project. I ran `pod install` and get the proper console output:

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing MBProgressHUD (0.9)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
```

I can see that my *MBProgressHUD.h* file exists in my Pods target under *Pods* > *MBProgressHUD* > *MBProgressHUD.h*

The issue is that when I add `#import MBProgressHUD.h` to a file, I get an error at that line reading "MBProgressHUD.h file not found".

Comment: Have you tried importing using the global import syntax? `#import <MBProgressHUD/MBProgressHUD.h>`

Comment: @Paul.s doesn't work :(

Comment: Is it odd that I don't see a Pods target when I click on my 'RRiOSApp' target? also, when I select the `Pods-RRiOSApp` scheme, it builds fine but I can't run it (not sure what that means!)

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer here, courtesy of @Ben-G: [iOS - Build fails with CocoaPods cannot find header files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002905/ios-build-fails-with-cocoapods-cannot-find-header-files)

I had not set up the Pod config for my test target in addition to my App target.

Comment: If I'd known this is a StackOverflow question ;)

Comment: This should get more votes as the responder has directed towards the exact source of issue with solution.