# Cocoapods missing pod include files when removing all test pods

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I have an iOS project I've been working on for some time, successfully, in which I used several pods for my main target, and then a couple more for my test target. Everything went swimmingly.

I was using a pod for tests, Expecta, because I needed to test asynchronous code. Now that Apple has added support for asynchronous testing in the latest Xcode, I rewrote my tests to use that, and want to remove Expecta from my project.

After doing that, my tests no longer compile, with errors about the header files from the pods no longer being found. For instance, `'FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h' file not found' error compiling one of my tests.

I've tried deleting all the Cocoapod-generated stuff and redoing it from `pod install` with no luck.

Versions: Cocoapods 0.35.0, Xcode 6.1.1, OS X 10.10.1.

My new, no-test-pods Podfile is:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '7.0'

target 'Meow' do
  pod 'AFNetworking', '2.4.1'
  pod 'TestFlightSDK', '3.0.2'
  pod 'AWSiOSSDKv2/S3', '2.0.11'
  pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK', '3.20.0'
  pod 'TTTAttributedLabel', '1.10.1'
  pod 'DTCoreText', '1.6.14'
  pod 'ReactiveCocoa', '2.3.1'
end

target 'MeowTests' do

end
```

Removing the MeowTests target hasn't helped either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I was typing the above :) I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002905/ios-build-fails-with-cocoapods-cannot-find-header-files); which says to add a `link_with` line to my podfile, and change the configuration file setup in the Info pane of my Project.

However, because I was *removing* the last pod from my test target, I also needed to delete the CocoaPods-specific phases from my test target. In the Build Phases tab, I removed `Check Pods Manifest.lock` and `Copy Pods Resources`.

Now my tests run fine. (And I can start rewriting them in Swift :) )