# AmazonServiceExceptionUnmarshaller.h file not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, amazon-web-services, cocoapods

Have you ever come across this error 'AmazonServiceExceptionUnmarshaller.h file not found' after installing the AWSiOSSDK 1.7.1 cocoapods?

[image]

I never faced it ever until today which unable to compile my project with it.

I have tried these potential solutions which were all failed unfortunately.

Ref: [iOS - Build fails with CocoaPods cannot find header files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002905/ios-build-fails-with-cocoapods-cannot-find-header-files)

It would be really good if you give me a piece of advices.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue myself. All because of the version of the cocoapods.
If your cocoapods v 0.39.0, you will face the error.
PLEASE DO NOT UPDATE THE LATEST COCOAPODS!

If you have already updated it, try this command line as follows:

`pod _0.38.2_ install`

You can install pods with the old version (v 0.38.2) by force.
It should be fine.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm getting this same error even with pod 0.38.2... any guess?