# swift 3 xcode 8 'MBProgressHUD.h' file not found failed to import bridging header '/myPath/myProj/myProj/myProj-Bridging-Header.h'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm using swift 3 xCode 8.My project's name is  jzy_weather2.

when I try to import  `MBProgressHUD.h` from the Pods, TWO error appears, one is `MBProgressHUD.h file not found`, the other is `failed to import bridging header /myPath/myProj/myProj/myProj-Bridging-Header.h`

This is the code in Podfile,Both Podfile's blocks below are OK when pod install

```
platform :ios, '10.0'
def myPods
  pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 1.0.0'
end

target 'jzy_weather2' do
  use_frameworks!
  myPods

  target 'jzy_weather2Tests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end

  target 'jzy_weather2UITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end
end
```

and also try like this

```
platform :ios, '10.0'

def myPods
  pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 1.0.0'
end

target 'jzy_weather2' do
  use_frameworks!
  myPods
end

target 'jzy_weather2Tests' do
  myPods
end

target 'jzy_weather2UITests' do
  myPods
end
```

the is the code that written in jzy_weather2-Bridging-Header.h

```
#import "MBProgressHUD.h"
```

and I've also tried this syntax

```
#import <MBProgressHUD.h>
```

and I've read some solutions like [there solutions in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002905/ios-build-fails-with-cocoapods-cannot-find-header-files), I don't know whether I've MISS some right solutions in this link, because there're too many solutions in it.

This is [my Project info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrYyj.jpg), I think this is the right solution for some one, but [My two errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWVDB.jpg) still occurs

Is there anything wrong with my configuration or code?
Or maybe in the xCode 8, I should write another kind of configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Drag and Drop these file in the project

MBProgressHUD.h

MBProgressHUD.m

You can find this

https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD

It will create bridging header in your app

Ex: jzy_weather -Bridging-Header.h

#import "MBProgressHUD.h"

Swift 3

```
let loadingMBProgress = MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: self.view, animated: true)

loadingMBProgress.mode = MBProgressHUDMode.indeterminate

loadingMBProgress.label.text = "Loading"

For hide

MBProgressHUD.hide(for: self.view, animated: true)
```

Comment: Here is what I've done before I ask the question:1)I new a project named jzy_weather2. 2)I use cocoapods install the

Comment: Here is what I've done before I ask the question:**(1)**I new a project named jzy_weather2. **(2)**I use cocoapods add MBProgressHUD to my project with the code in my question, this step is ok, which means I add MBProgressHUD to the project successfully **(3)**I create a bridge header file in my Project, I've write the `#import "MBProgressHUD.h"` to import the MBProgressHUD, **THEN the two errors occurs**