# ld: library not found for -lAFNetworking xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, afnetworking

I am a total newbie to ios programming. Cloned a friends project. When trying to build (after resolving a lot of other errors), I get the following error:

```
ld: library not found for -lAFNetworking
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I checked the Pod file and searched for AFNetworking in the project, and it is there. Don't know what is going wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message indicates that the library was not found.

Make sure that:

1. You see the AFNetworking in your Pods directory.
2. Your Pods directory is in the search paths. Go to the project -> Build Settings -> Search for 'search paths' and make sure that your Pods directory is there. You can add it by adding "${PROJECT_DIR}/Pods" for example.

Comment: with the help of Albert.Qing's answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002905/ios-build-fails-with-cocoapods-cannot-find-header-files, the problem was resolved. Thanks

Comment: Hi, after doing that, I got another 20 errors apparently due to the AFnetworking version I was using. I changed it to version 2 on the Pod file and did pod install, now, again, I get the same error. What could be going wrong there?

Comment: Check if indeed the Pod install updated the AFNetworking package. When running pod install it should list the version installed and you can also find it in the Podfile.lock.  See also this link - https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/pod-install-vs-update.html

Comment: Hi, yeah. It is installed. When I set the search paths, should it be for the project or the targets? To be safe, I set the search paths everywhere to be ${PODS_ROOT}; still no luck.

Comment: If the project uses CocoaPods be aware to always open the .xcworkspace file instead of the .xcodeproj file

Answer (score 11):

also make sure you are running the .xcworkspace project (white icon),not the .xcodeproj project (blue icon)

[image: green box == .xcworkspace project]

Answer (score 4):

add `$(inherited)` flag to `LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS` at `build settings` in Xcode target.

Answer (score 4):

1.Remove Path from Other Linker flags
2.Clean the build
3.Run the code

Answer (score 0):

please try to install COCOAPOD app in your mac.

Try to re attached AFNetworking [here is the link please follow the instruction](https://guides.cocoapods.org)

Answer (score -1):

If you are using CocoaPods please check that you are opening .xcworkspace  file not the .xcodeproj file. The difference lies in icon color. xcworkspace icon is white while xcodeproj is of blue color