# .h file not linking when pod install

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoapods-1.1.1

Mac OS 10.12
xcode 8.1

We are trying to install pod like

```
platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'ProjectName' do
pod 'ARSafariActivity', '~> 0.0'
pod 'FFBadgedBarButtonItem', '~> 1.0'
pod 'MMDrawerController', '~> 0.5'
pod 'MMProgressHUD', '~> 0.2'
pod 'MMSpreadsheetView', '~> 0.0'
pod 'Mantle', '~> 1.5'
pod 'Masonry', '~> 0.5'
pod 'NHAlignmentFlowLayout', '~> 0.1'
pod 'NMRangeSlider', '~> 1.1'
pod 'PBWebViewController', '~> 0.2'

pod 'SZTextView', '~> 1.1'
pod 'AAPLAdvancedCollectionView', :git => 'https://github.com/zwaldowski/AAPLAdvancedCollectionView.git', :tag => 'v1.0.11'
end
target 'ProjectNameTests' do
pod 'Kiwi', '~> 2.3'
pod 'OHHTTPStubs', '~> 4.0'
end
```

Giving error lexical and preprocessor issue.
Mantle.h file not found.

We tried with [iOS - Build fails with CocoaPods cannot find header files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002905/ios-build-fails-with-cocoapods-cannot-find-header-files) this still not working.

Comment: did you tried this:`right click your project` -> `Add Files to "prjectName" ...` -> `Choose the Mantle  dir in Pods dir` ? then import `Mantle.h`?

Answer (score 0):

You should specify to use frameworks if you are not planning to add bridging file between swift and Objective - c

**Using Pods without Bridge file**

update your pod file to

```
platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'ProjectName' do
use_frameworks!
pod 'ARSafariActivity', '~> 0.0'
pod 'FFBadgedBarButtonItem', '~> 1.0'
pod 'MMDrawerController', '~> 0.5'
pod 'MMProgressHUD', '~> 0.2'
pod 'MMSpreadsheetView', '~> 0.0'
pod 'Mantle', '~> 1.5'
pod 'Masonry', '~> 0.5'
pod 'NHAlignmentFlowLayout', '~> 0.1'
pod 'NMRangeSlider', '~> 1.1'
pod 'PBWebViewController', '~> 0.2'

pod 'SZTextView', '~> 1.1'
pod 'AAPLAdvancedCollectionView', :git => 'https://github.com/zwaldowski/AAPLAdvancedCollectionView.git', :tag => 'v1.0.11'
end
target 'ProjectNameTests' do
pod 'Kiwi', '~> 2.3'
pod 'OHHTTPStubs', '~> 4.0'
end
```

Now you dont need to import .h files, it gets imported as modules :)

I hope you can see `use_frameworks!` in updated pod file :)

**Using Pods with Bridge file (if you dont want to deal with frameworks but work only with Objective - C files directly)**

Create a .h file with name `YourAppName-Bridging-header.h`
open it and add all the Objective - C files you want to import for example

```
#ifndef YourAppName_Bridging_Header_h
#define YourAppName_Bridging_Header_h


#endif /* YourAppName_Bridging_Header_h */

#import "Reachability.h"
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h>
```

Thats it now you can use it in any of the files without worrying to import them again and again.