# Including a pod inside a framework target: file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, xcode8, ios-frameworks

I'm using framework targets (for better code reuse and IB_Designables), and I've already had a framework target working perfectly. I've decided to move some other classes to a framework target too.

I've set up the pods (just a single one in this case), but whenever I try to include the pod I'm getting not found error.

[image]

No change if I try to use the modules approach too:

[image]

The problem is that I've already got another framework too, with the same settings (cross checked all the compiler settings/linker flags/build phases etc) and that framework has no issue importing its pods.

Here is my podfile (`TUComponents` is the working on, `TUModels` is the failing one):

```
[...]
target 'TUComponents' do


    pod 'AHKNavigationController'
    pod 'TTTAttributedLabel'

    use_frameworks!


end

target 'TUModels' do


    pod 'JSONModel'

    use_frameworks!


end
```

Even weirder; Xcode has no problem code-completing importing the `JSONModel/JSONModel.h` header (or `JSONModel` in case of module @import). But when I try to compile, it fails.

What might be wrong with my configuration?

**UPDATE:** If I give up using frameworks in pods and use regular old static library, and set allow non-modular includes in frameworks to YES, I can build. But I have no idea why I can't build when using Pod frameworks.

Comment: Delete your derived data, clean the project, then re-build

Comment: @JacobBoyd unfortunately, no change. cleaned build folder/project, closed xcode, deleted derived data, relaunched. no avail.

Comment: Does JSONModel export JSONModel.h as a public header file? Non public headers can not be imported across targets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe try solution from: https://www.natashatherobot.com/cocoapods-installing-same-pod-multiple-targets/

```text
platform :ios, '9.0'

use_frameworks!

# My other pods

def testing_pods
    pod 'JSONModel'
end

target 'TUComponents' do
    pod 'AHKNavigationController'
    pod 'TTTAttributedLabel'
    testing_pods
end

target 'TUModels' do
    testing_pods
end
```

Answer (score 1):

From  [iOS - Build fails with CocoaPods cannot find header files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002905/ios-build-fails-with-cocoapods-cannot-find-header-files) :

> Make sure your Podfile includes link_with on targets missing a config file. Cocoapods only sets the first target by default otherwise. e.g.

```
platform :osx, '10.7'
pod 'JSONKit',       '~> 1.4'

link_with 'Pomo', 'Pomo Dev', 'Pomo Tests'
```

Answer (score 0):

Restarting Xcode fixed it for me

Answer (score 0):

The following steps worked in my case:

1. Quit the Xcode n Simulator
2. Delete Drived data
3. Again open your project
4. Clear it

Answer (score 0):

I have also encountered [a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76041294/xcode-error-xxx-h-file-not-found-when-importing-headers-from-pod-dependency).

I struggled with it for two days but was able to solve it unexpectedly. I selected the framework target that depends on a Pod, went to "Build Settings" > "Packaging" > "Defines Module" and set it to "No". Then I rebuilt the target and the error disappeared. I'm not sure about the exact reason why this worked, but it did solve the problem for me. I hope this information helps you. If you have a more in-depth understanding of this issue, please feel free to share your insights.