# 'Chrono' file not found issue - iOS

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, cocoapods, abseil

I have few Firebase libraries integrated into my ongoing iOS project and recently I got a 'chrono file not found' error as you can see below:

[image]

I am stuck with this for past 2 days. I went through several forums & SO as usual ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002905/ios-build-fails-with-cocoapods-cannot-find-header-files),[and this](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1610)).
But none of the helped and really can't find an accepted solution for this anywhere yet. And another weird thing is Xcode auto code completion and console logging not working after this. My pod file looks like this:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
 platform: ios, '13.0'

target 'LearningApp' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
   use_frameworks!

  # Pods for LearningApp


  pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod 'SDWebImagePDFCoder'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'MessageKit'
  pod 'GoogleSignIn'
  pod 'SwiftKeychainWrapper'

  
  target 'LearningAppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'LearningAppUITests' do
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Right now I am using Xcode 12.0.1 and Swift 5.
I am really stuck with this, hope someone can help.

Answer (score 1):

I got a solution, this worked for me. Hope this may  help someone.

1. Do `pod deintegrate` from terminal.
2. Add `Firebase frameworks` using `Swift Package Manager` ([Check here for How to add Firebase Package Manager](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/SwiftPackageManager.md)).
3. Install other pods if needed.

And go!

Comment: I was also stuck with this for past 2 days. This solution finally worked. I just remove all the Firebase from my podfile and then using swift package manager added them again. Thanks mate!